# React : LocalStorage with a non-null value always

Tags: node.js, reactjs, local-storage

Hello I am using localStorage to save my jwt token from my api
But it is saving my token even if I close shut down the node server and etc.
and I would need to do a login check

here is my server route

```
app.route('/login')
        .post(async (req,res)=>{

            try {
                const response = await usersControllers.signin(req.body);
                const login = response.login;
                console.log(login);
                if(login.id && login.isValid){
                    const payload = {id: login.id};
                    res.json({
                        token: jwt.sign({data:payload}, app.config.jwt.secret,{expiresIn: '60'}),
                        response
                    });
                }else{
                    console.log('entrou here');
                    res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                } 
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('entrou here');
                console.error(error.message);
                res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        })
```

and in my front end react

i have this in my login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Form,FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, Alert} from 'reactstrap';
import Header from '../../components/header';

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log(this.props);
        this.state = {
            message: this.props.location.state?this.props.location.state.message: '',
        };
    }

    signIn = () => {
        const data = {login:this.login,password:this.password};
        const requestInfo = {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({data}),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }),
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/login', requestInfo)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error("Login Invalido..")
        })
        .then(token => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', token.token);
            this.props.history.push("/users");
            return;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.setState({message: e.message})
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <Header title="ReactJS Login"/>
                <hr className="my-3"/>
                {
                    this.state.message !== ''? (
                    <Alert color="danger" className ="text-center"> {this.state.message}</Alert>
                    ) : ''
                }
                <Form>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="login">Login</Label>
                        <Input type="text" id="login" onChange={e => this.login = e.target.value } placeholder="Informe seu login" />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="password">Senha</Label>
                        <Input type="text" id="password" onChange={e => this.password = e.target.value }  placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.signIn}> Entrar </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

here i set my jwt in localstorage:

```
.then(token => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token.token);
    this.props.history.push("/users");
    return;
})
```

in my other js file 
my auth about jwt

```
const isAuth = () => {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    if(localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
        console.log("entrou aq2");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

in console.log(localStorage.getItem('token')); have value !== all time

Even without logging in with my api

Comment: Values in `localStorage` will never expire. Maybe you can consider using `sessionStorage` instead ?

Comment: @dev_junwen 
How could I create a sessionStorage?

Comment: I'm having a problem I'm using redirect to move unauthenticated user to home, but it's not working.

Comment: Is there any other "more correct" option or is sessionStorage the best?

Comment: Usually we store `accessToken` in browsers cookie, not `localStorage` nor `sessionStorage`. I am guessing the problem you have now is the token is always in your `localStorage` since it will never expire. You can try and remove it manually to see if that's the problem. If you are using chrome, open up your console and navigate to the `Application` tab, then look for `Storage` menu and select `Local Storage`, select your domain URL and clear it.

Comment: @dev_junwen It worked
The problem was this value that never changed.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can learn how to add acesstoken in the cookie browser

Comment: https://jcbaey.com/authentication-in-spa-reactjs-and-vuejs-the-right-way?utm_source=medium&utm_campaign=spa-authentication

Comment: @dev_junwen ty bro if u want can post reply for i give rep +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your

```js
localStorage.getItem('token') !== null
```

is returning `true` is because you are using `localStorage`. `localStorage`'s values does not expire therefore your value is stored in your `localStorage` until you call

```js
localStorage.removeItem('token')
```

If you want your `token` be deleted after each time you close your browser, use `sessionStorage` instead. You can read more about authenticating with SPA [here](https://jcbaey.com/authentication-in-spa-reactjs-and-vuejs-the-right-way?utm_source=medium&utm_campaign=spa-authentication)

Comment: Hello thank you bro I don't speak english very well so I don't know if I understood very well, I read everything, especially this part:

Double submitted cookies
and
What about putting a JWT inside a cookie to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: Basically you need to get the concept of the whole authentication process right. Then you can implement you own way of authentication, this is just an example :)

Comment: Got it, but about Double submitted cookies

create a cookie when the user enters the site and save this value when a form is made and verify,
Is it a good option?

About generate
(cryptographically strong) pseudorandom value
could i do this using bcrypt?

Comment: I will probably create an example of authentication app in the future. I will let you know if I did that so that you can take a look on how I implement the authentication flow.

Comment: thanks broooooo  
i managed to make my front end reach r in my api i am just having difficulty validating my token
my front end correctly sends my token

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848506/passport-jwt-jwt-not-validating-on-backend

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify() to save in localstorage

```
.then(token => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token.token));
    this.props.history.push("/users");
    return;
})
```

and use JSON.parse() to get from localstorage

```
const isAuth = () => {
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')) !== null) {
        console.log("entrou aq2");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Even closing the server by restarting pc, etc. 
And I set the 60 second token time

Comment: @gabriel you want session out once you close tab?

Comment: yes 
Yes I got it, but because of localsession it keeps the token forever then it doesn't enter my else

Comment: But I don't know what better way to store my token